# Problems virtualizing SBS2003 server to KVM on Debian

Tags: windows, virtualization, windows-server-2003, debian-squeeze, kvm-virtualization

I have a server with sbs2003. I would like to move it to another machine (linux Squeeze Debian), within a KVM virtual machine.
I proceeded like this:

- Installed the disk2vhd.exe application on the physical SBS2003 server
- Created an image file (sbs2003.img) on the fly
- Moved the image to a Samba share directory on the Debian machine:
- Converted sbs2003.img to vhd format:

  ```
  kvm-img convert -f vpc -O rwa sbs2003.vdh sbs2003.img
  ```
- Created the virtual machine

When I run the new VM I get the following message:

```
system32\drivers\ntfs.sys missing or damaged
```

Did I do something wrong in the process? How can I fix this?

**Update 1**
When I boot the CD, I have the following messages:

```
Starting SeaBios (version ...)
```

Booting from CD-ROM
Boot failed: could not read from CDROM
No bootable device

Answer (score 1):

Rather than retrying the P2V process, you may simply try repairing the OS, failing that, try an in-place upgrade as MS suggests here: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/816579

> 1. Insert the Windows Server 2003 CD in the CD-ROM drive or the DVD-ROM drive, and then restart the computer. Windows Setup begins.
> 2. Press ENTER (to continue) when the Welcome to Setup window appears.
> 3. Press F8 to accept the License Agreement.
> 4. Use the arrow keys to highlight the Windows Server 2003 installation that you want to upgrade, and then press R (to Repair).
>
> Note If the Setup program does not detect a previous installation but just continues to the partitioning screen, an in-place upgrade may not be possible. To detect an existing installation, the Boot.ini file must be correct, the installed registry files must be intact, and the build number must be the same. If these are not all true, Setup will not find the installation to do an in-place upgrade.

**UPDATE 1 - For OP comment:**

You need to repair the VM, not the original box. It's very possible that some of the system files were not able to be read to the VM. It's also possible the hardware change may have been substantial between the physical box and the VM. Either of these possibilities are much easier to resolve by first trying a repair.

Any good virtualization system should support mounting either the physical optical drive on the host to the VM, or an ISO or disk image as a virtual optical drive. If your system cannot do both of these, you should do more research before deploying virtual machines.

If you cannot mount an optical disk or a disk image, you are significantly limited in how you can interact with your VMs.

So, find out how to either map the hosts optical drive to your VM (this will be in the VM host management software), or turn your sbs2003 disk into an ISO (https://superuser.com/questions/166996/simple-utility-to-rip-isos-on-windows-7) and mount it, and run the repair features.

Comment: But my sbs2003 runs perfectly ! I don't need to repair it on my first machine but rather on the second physical machine, in the VM, no ? I cannot run the sbs2003 cd rom on my linux server !?

Comment: @user62025 - Have you triend to repair the installation on the virtual machine

Comment: See update: You need to be able to mount ISOs or your physical optical drive to a VM.

Comment: @Ramhound - Yes but I have the message "CD not bootable". On windows this cd is bootable. I changed of course the boot sequence.

Comment: @user62025 - You need to determine the reason the cd is not bootable before you can fix your problem.

Comment: read my update ! I don't know the reason !!

Comment: I must precise: the physical source machine is windows, the physical target machine is linux.

Comment: see you tomorrow ...

Comment: With your help I installed the CDROM in my VM. Now I can boot from it. When I press R (for repair) I have a message that no disk reader is installed. Is is really the right demarch to solve my problem ?

Comment: Is that talking about a floppy disk?

Comment: No. I have one virtio (path to sbs2003.img) and one IDE CDROM (path to sr0).

Comment: have you tried using `virt-p2v`?

Comment: no. Is it the solution or a suggestion ? does it means that kvm-img is not the right tool ?

Comment: forget my last question. No I didn't try it. I must try it.